# tap-win32 networking in colinux / portable_ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to set up two network adapters on portable ubuntu remix, which is based on colinux; one slirp for outgoing access, and one tap for fast communication with the host. The slirp host works just fine, but I can't communicate between the host and colinux using the tap interface.

I added the tap interface by downloading http://www.henrynestler.com/colinux/tools/netdriver-tap84.zip and running

```
tapcontrol.exe install OemWin2k.inf TAP0801co
```

. I renamed it to coLinux_Tap, so that it would be easy to differentiate between this and the Tap adapter I have for OpenVPN. I configured it with a static IP, 192.168.3.1/255.255.255.0, no gateway.

I added

```
eth1=tuntap,"coLinux_Tap"
```

to my portable_ubuntu.conf file, and added a static config to /etc/networking/interfaces which reads:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.3.2
network 192.168.3.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.3.255
```

When I boot Portable Ubuntu, the device remains disconnected, and no packets are seen in windows as being either sent or received. Ping from Windows returns "request timed out". Ping from Linux also times out, although there at least ifconfig indicates packets being sent (but not received) on eth1.

I've also tried forcing the "media connected" option in Windows to Always instead of Application Controlled, with no change.
Any ideas?

EDIT: I think my routes are OK(ish).

If the device is not set to always connected, then no route exists for 192.168.3.anything, and it can't be added. If I force the coLinux_Tap device to be connected, it has a route set already:

```
c:\>route print | grep 192.168.3
      192.168.3.0    255.255.255.0      192.168.3.1     192.168.3.1       20
      192.168.3.1  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       20
    192.168.3.255  255.255.255.255      192.168.3.1     192.168.3.1       20
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      192.168.3.1     192.168.3.1       20
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      192.168.3.1     192.168.3.1       1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

The portable ubuntu release does not included the daemon needed to attach to the TAP device!

I downloaded the 0.7.3 release from http://www.henrynestler.com/colinux/releases/0.7.3/packages/daemons-0.7.3-20080524.zip, and extracted colinux-net-daemon.exe to my portable ubuntu directory; now everything works correctly! (although the default DISPLAY is still the slirp device, but that's easy enough to fix).

Answer (score 0):

Man.  I've been through so many variations of pear-shaped with colinux and TAP that I'm sure I must have seen this one, but it's like a maze of twisty little network configs in my mind.

Maybe give this a try, from `cmd` on the Windows side:

```
route add 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.3.1
```

Hopefully it will figure out to use the TAP adapter.  If not, you might be able to tell it to with `IF 2` or whatever on the end, if you can figure out what interface number it is.

If that doesn't work, you might want to try bridging your TAP adapter and Local Area Connection (some form of that exists, I hope?).  Disgusting, I know, and prone to screwing things up, but I've wound up forced to do it at least once.

Comment: I added my post to indicate the route [that way I could get formatting].

I don't want to bridge the TAP and local network: I want networking to work via slirp, as I can't attach another device to my company network.